# A different method for solving 2nd order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, education

For constants $a,b$ there are many ways to find the solutions to

$$y^{\prime\prime} + (a+b)y^\prime + aby = \phi(x). $$

Perhaps the most popular is to first solve the homogeneous case when $\phi(x) = 0$ and then find a particular solution using the 'guess and check' method.

There seems to be an easier way by solving this as two first order ODEs, and my questions are:

1. is this way easier (in your opinion)?
2. if so, why do we not teach people to do this the easier way? And,
3. does the method described below have a name?

I claim the easier way is to make the substitution $u = y^\prime + ay$. Then the original 2nd order ODE can be written as a first order linear ODE
$$ u^\prime + bu = \phi(x). $$
Once we solve this equation for $u$, we then return to our substitution
$$ y^\prime + ay = u.$$
The solutions to this first order linear ODE are the solutions to the original second order ODE.

Here is a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZLU0MCqAHk) clip of me explaining this method in the case when $a=b$.

Comment: This is especially easy in your example because the coefficients are on a particular form : $a+b$ and $ab$. So, it is of very limited range of use. In case of more general form of constant coefficients, this is equivalent to a particular case of the "Reduction of order" thechnique : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order . Teaching the general method is more fruitful for a larger range of applications.

Comment: Hi @JJacquelin, I'd believe this method is different from the reduction of order method. When $a=b$ reduction of order asks us to guess solutions of the form $v(x) e^{-ax}$. This method requires no guessing.

Comment: Also having the coefficients in the form $a+b$ and $ab$ is more to save us the trouble of solving the characteristic equation than a specialisation of the general constant coefficient case. So I don't see the loss of generality here.

Answer (score 1):

This is my preferred method. In general, let
$$
\partial _{x}^{2}y-c\partial _{x}y-dy=\varphi (x)
$$
Set
$$
y_{1}=y,\;y_{2}=\partial _{x}y
$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{x}y_{1} &=&y_{2} \\
\partial _{x}y_{2} &=&dy_{1}+cy_{2}+\varphi (x)
\end{eqnarray*}
or
$$
\partial _{x}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_{1} \\
y_{2}
\end{array}
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
d & c
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_{1} \\
y_{2}
\end{array}
\right) +\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\varphi  \\
0
\end{array}
\right) =A\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_{1} \\
y_{2}
\end{array}
\right) +\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\varphi  \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
so
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_{1}(x) \\
y_{2}(x)
\end{array}
\right) =\exp [Ax]\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_{1}(0) \\
y_{2}(0)
\end{array}
\right) +\int_{0}^{x}dy\exp [A(x-y)]\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\varphi (y) \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Interesting, but that does not answer any of the three questions stated by OP.

Comment: The first question is about an opinion which is not allowed. So I stated that it is my preferred method, a fact rather than an opinion. The method I outlined is in part in response to Jacquelin's remark about the OP's case being a special one. I do not know why it is not teached nor do I know if it has a specific name.